# Adding app id in source code

Tags: android, admob

When I tried to add app id given by ad-mob in gradle. After syncing it changes package name automatically and gives me error like this
saying '-' does not valid in package name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you add the id you are getting from admob. You set the admob id inside activity where you want to display your ad. The place where you are trying to set is a package name of your application. It has nothing to do with admob.

```
mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("HERE IS WHERE YOUR ID GOES");
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("1111")
.build();
mInterstitial.loadAd(request);
```

That's just an example.
Check here for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qCxo0D-Sak

Answer (score 0):

You are adding Id at wrong place put here if you are displaying Interstitial ads

```
  mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this); 
mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("Your id ");
```

If you are using banner then put id  here

```
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is about package name.`-` is not allowed in package name.

Android follows normal java package conventions according to Android developer [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) :

> A full Java-language-style package name for the Android application.
>   The name should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase
>   letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However,
>   individual package name parts may only start with letters.

`ca-app-pub-9282266180865953~5714702220` is an AdUnit id that you placed in wrong place as package name.

If you want to add banner Ad follow [these](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) steps else If want to add Interstitial Ad follow [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) one.